# Which is correct: "of my own will" or "of my own free will"?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage, difference, phrase-choice

Situation: I purchased a book. However, no one demanded that I purchase the book.

Which of the following should I say?

> 1. I purchased the book **of my own free will.**
> 2. I purchased the book **on my own.**
> 3. I purchased the book **by my own will**.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is good. The word "free" there is semi-redundant, and adds a little emphasis and clarity.

The second one sounds more like the speaker used his own money to buy the book without help, or perhaps the speaker's parents wouldn't take him to the bookstore and he had to walk, and so it is worth avoiding saying it this way.  If your meaning is already clear, though, it is often an acceptable way to rephrase.

The third is a bit awkward, and I strongly prefer "of" to "by". It's meaning is clear though, and it is okay to not use the word "free".

I can mention that when "will" is used as a noun, it can also refer to the legal document that specifies a person's wishes regarding what happens to their estate when they die.  Mostly, though, "will" is used as a verb to express future tense - but it can also be a verb meaning someone "wishes" or "wants that" some action is taken by someone, or by some group that may include the person.  This use is fairly archaic, and tends to be reserved for when the biblical God is doing the willing. (e.g. "God wills that all be saved.")

Because the word is so commonly used for other things, I would often include the word "free" if I were in your situation, and in a discussion where I must use the term repeatedly I would vary between using "free" and dropping it, and occasionally say "of my own volition" instead for additional variety, or use constructions like "because I wanted to", or sometimes the one you gave, "on my own", which sound less formal. In some cases it is helpful to restate the idea with something like "Nobody coerced me." or "Nobody made me (*do it*)."  The term "free will" calls to mind timeless philosophical debates about the nature of consciousness and the human mind (i.e. "Do we have free will?"), and I would wish to subtly distance myself from those connotations.
A thorough comparison of all of the ways to express that one acted autonomously would take some time, as there are quite a few acceptable and natural ways if you consider the informal ones.